# How to conditionally create a hyperlink based on value of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, conditional-formatting

```
ColA                  Col B              ColC
Project A            A.pdf               A.pdf
Project B                                No Link
```

I have a list of project records. One column (e.g., B) may have a reference to a pdf file. If I create a formula

```
=if(isblank(B2),"No Link",hyperlink(folderURL + B2),B2)
```

What I want is to place a hyperlink on only those rows where column B contains a pdf reference, and insert text "No Link". I get the proper text values, but in all rows have the hyperlnk default appearance and behavior -- Excel seems to be creating "phantom links" out of the "No Link" cells.

[image]

Clicking on the "No Link" value in Col C activates an attempt to open the file listed in Col B, which returns a No file found error.

Answer (score 13):

It's unclear if this is a bug; but Excel seems to be making the entire cell clickable just because there's a `HYPERLINK` function in the formula in order for it to work. Right-clicking on the cell & selecting **Remove Hyperlink** does not seem to work either.

I can't seem to find a non-VBA solution to prevent Excel from creating those "phantom" hyperlinks, but here's a stopgap for the "Cannot open the specified file" error:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address"),"NO LINK"), HYPERLINK(folderURL & B2,B2))
```

Instead of displaying just "No Link" if `B2` is empty, the formula creates a hyperlink that points back to the cell itself. The cell will still be clickable, but the error message won't show up.

<sup>Source: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/340575-solved-conditional-hyperlink.html</sup>

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a bug. Per [Office documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010062412.aspx): "When you click the cell that contains the HYPERLINK function, Microsoft Excel opens the file that is stored at link_location."

Comment: @gm2 I think you're misunderstanding the OP's question. Excel is creating a "phantom" hyperlink even if you don't mean to.

Comment: I understand the behavior of Excel that the OP describes, and I think your answer is a nice solution (and I +1'd it) without using VBA. My point was that the current Office documentation suggests that this behavior is intended. I understood it to mean "Excel _will_ act on a cell containing HYPERLINK() by following a link that's presented as an argument". Taking another look now, however, the docs could be more explicit and maybe mention this limitation.

Comment: Interestingly this "[Unusual Behavior](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156926)" was confirmed to be a problem in Excel 97.

Comment: I'm using `HYPERLINK("")` for the failure case in this workaround (also works with `IFERROR` around the proper hyperlink), gives you a blank cell with no link.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what the OP is trying to do but this worked for me

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address"),""), HYPERLINK("http://someurl","friendly_link_name"))
```

You get an empty, non-clickable cell when there is no link.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2);HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#"; ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()));"NO LINK"); HYPERLINK(folderURL & B2;B2))
```

Using `CONCATENATE("#"; ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()))` in the dummy hyperlink makes the full formula ready to be context aware.